# EnumDropDownListFor is not setting selected value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, enums, asp.net-mvc-views, enumdropdownlistfor

I am trying to use EnumDropDownListFor in the following fashion:

```
@Html.EnumDropDownListFor(model => model.Title, "Select a Title", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

But it is not setting the selected value. I have even tried setting the title in the line before but it has not worked. I am using this code in the same view for a different enum and it works fine and the code above works fine on other pages as well.
The declaration of the property is like this:

```
[DataMember]
public Title Title { get; set; }
```

and the enum looks like this:

```
public enum Title
{
    Ms = 1,
    Miss,
    Mrs,
    Mr,
    Master,
    Rev,
    Fr,
    Dr,
    Prof,
    Lady,
    Lord,
    Sir
}
```

The rest of the view was auto generated by vs2017.
Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

After trying to reduce my code for displaying purposes I have discovered that the problem is that I was setting ViewBag.Title which was somehow confusing it. After removing that it started working again. That is a bit odd but I'm just happy I fixed the issue.